# How to add rows based on Unique values of other columns in pandas

Tags: pandas

Let's say I have a data frame that looks like this

[image]

For Each Unique Store there are 6 Unique MRP Values
which is 1999., 2499., 2699., 2799., 2999., 4499, So for some the Unique Stores there is not all the price values which means sales_aty is for them is zero. How can i find those Unique Store and if any of the price is not there then add that store with missed MRP value and sales qty as zero

Comment: `df.set_index(['STORE', 'MRP']).fillna(0)`?

Answer (score 0):

Use a join. First make an index based on all combinations you are expecting. Then try to join your dataframe. A left join will leave the index values without data as null. Apply logic to fill in nulls to suit your needs.

```py
import itertools
import pandas as pd
store_ids = df['STORE'].drop_duplicates()
mrp_values = (1999, 2499, 2699, 2799, 2999)
keys = itertools.product(store_ids, mrp_values)
temp = pd.DataFrame.from_records([{'store_id': store_id, 'mrp': mrp_value}
                                  for store_id, mrp_value in keys])
result = temp.merge(df, how="left", left_on=["store_id", "mrp"],
                                    right_on=["STORE", "MRP"])
# apply null-handling logic to result...
```

Comment: Thanks, Man it worked:)
Is there a way where we handle this by just using Panda's core capabilities.
Because even I tried using ducts, the list it worked, but it cannot be used in Production.

Comment: Can you clarify more what your production constraints are? Itertools is a builtin module in python 3, shouldn't be a problem. As for pandas, you are using two parts of pandas DataFrame api: the `from_records` constructor and the `merge` method. Should be fine.